# How to send a success message with get_success_url() in Django FormView

Tags: django-forms, django-class-based-views

I've got `FormView` that redirect to a previous page if the form was valid. That's works fine but how can I tell a user that the information has been posted? I want him to see a success message in a modal window after redirect.

I've tried to do it through `request.session` in `get_success_url` but it doesn't fit to my goals because a user can submit the form multiple times. So how can I return any message with redirect in `get_success_url` in `FormView`?

My `FormView`

```
class CatPhotoUploadFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'blank.html'
    form_class = CatPhotoForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        self.request.session['success_message'] = 'Everything is fine'
        return reverse('cat:detail_cat', args=(self.kwargs['pk'],))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        cat = Cat.objects.filter(id__exact=self.kwargs['pk'])
        for each in form.cleaned_data['attachments']:
            print('****', each, '****', type(each))
            Photo.objects.create(photo_path=each, photo_author=self.request.user, photo_cat = cat[0])
        return super(CatPhotoUploadFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Have you looked into using Django's [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Django messaging framework for this purpose, change `get_success_url` with message.

```
from django.contrib import messages
def get_success_url(self):
    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'form submission success')
    return reverse('cat:detail_cat', args=(self.kwargs['pk'],))
```

In your template, something like this ( NOTE: remember to pass messages )

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Request  object is not available in get_success_url

Comment: Use `self.request` (_«Edits must be at least 6 characters»_)

Answer (score 6):

In fact Django has a ready to use mixin, [SuccessMessageMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views), which can be use in class based views to achieve the same purpose.

Like so:

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

class CatPhotoUploadFormView(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'blank.html'
    form_class = CatPhotoForm
    success_message = 'Everything is fine'
    ...
```

Very clean and straightforward.

Comment: This is not a correct answer : question is about using `messages` **and** using `get_success_url()` method. `success_message` looks like _ignored_ in this use case.

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_success_url(self):
    from django.contrib import messages
    messages.success(self.request, 'Yes it works!')
```

Comment: The only answer that worked for me. @Renjith Thankachan tip generated an error : `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'function'` Just added at the end the `return reverse` (Django 3)

Answer (score 1):

This will do the work

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    print(self.request.POST)
    form.save()
    messages.add_message(
        self.request,
        messages.SUCCESS,
        'User registered sucessfully'
    )
    return super().form_valid(form)
```